# Does the Mpemba Effect affect none-water substances?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, water, thermal-conductivity, liquid-state

Does the Mpemba Effect work on liquids other than water? If so, what are the similarities/differences, and what contributes to it(mainly the differences)?